# Dynamic programming and Bellman equation to obtain the maximum

Tags: stochastic-calculus, finance-mathematics, optimization, mathematics, sde

This is the problem of Marhsall (1992) "Inflation and Asset Returns in a Monetary Economy" and Balvers and Huang (2009) "Money and the C-CAPM"

Suppose an endowment economy where the representative agent maximizes her expeced lifetime utility subject to a budget constraint and given that transaction costs to purchase consumption goods are mitigated by money holdings, that is: 
$$
    V(w_t,m_t,x_t)=\max_{c_t,\mu_t,\{s_t^i\}_{i=1}^{n}}\left(u(c_t)+\delta\mathbb{E}_{t}\left[V(w_{t+1},m_{t+1}, x_{t+1}\right)]\right) \quad (1)$$
     $$\text{subject to}\quad w_{t+1}=R_{t+1}\left[w_t-c_t-T(c_t,m_t) + m_t -\mu_t\right] \quad (2)$$
     $$ R_{t+1}=\sum_{i=0}^{n}s_t^i R_{t+1}^{i}, \quad \sum_{i=0}^{n}s_t^i=1 \quad\text{and} \quad (3)$$
    $$m_{t+1} = (\mu_t + z_{t+1})/\pi_{t+1} \quad (4)$$
where

- $w_t,$ real financial wealth (excluding money holdings)
- $m_t,$ real money holdings
- $x_t,$ set of state variables, exogenous to the consumer-investor, that is sufficient to represent changes in the investment opportunity set
- $c_t,$ current consumption
- $\mu_t$, real money holdings (for use in the upcoming period)
- $\pi_{t+1}=p_{t+1}/p_t$, gross inflation rate
- $z_{t+1} = (M_{t+1} - M_{t})/p_t$, transfer of government revenues from money creation
- $T(c_t,m_t)$ represents the real transaction cost of purchasing the current level of consumption
- so $m_{t+1}$ are the deflated money holdings of the next period

And it also holds for $T(\cdot,\cdot)$ that it is twice differentiable and also:

- $T(c_t,m_t)\geq 0$, $T_{c}(c_t,m_t)> 0$, $T_{m}(c_t,m_t)< 0$
- $T_{cc}(c_t,m_t)\geq 0$, $T_{mm}(c_t,m_t)\geq 0$ and $T_{cm}(c_t,m_t)\leq 0$

I cite the problem above, since it's been years from the last time I have a course in dynamic programming and at the moment I am struggling to solve it.

This is from the appendix of the paper. This is all about the solution of the problem and nothing else
[image: This is from the appendix of the paper. This is all about the solution of the problem and nothing else]

Comment: I mention here, that the indexes of the function $T(\cdot,\cdot)$ denote the partial derivative with respect to consumption, the money holdings and the cross derivative of consumtpion and money holdings etc. Also $\delta$ in the RHS of the value of lifetime utlility is a subjective discount factor.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Yes, isn't that obvious? How to solve this problem. How to take the FOC and by using the Bellman equqation to find the maximum...

Comment: You will not get a closed form solution to this very complex problem. Even proving the existence of V would -- I think -- require stating additional conditions on u, mu, and some general equilibrium conditions. Perhaps you would be satisfied if someone were to help you write the Lagrangian function that can be used to derive the first-order conditions in the appendix of the paper. These conditions may be as close as the author of the paper gets to a (numerical) solution of the Bellman equation, in any case.

Comment: Well, the paper is not clear about the additional conditions that you say. Specifically, it does not tell a word. What I can tell you for sure is that $u(\cdot)$ as a utility function must satisfy some properties like increasing and concave function by assumption. Nothing more...I am compmletely confused

Comment: Writing down the Lagrangian seems like a good first step

Comment: By the Lagrangian, do you mean this? 
$$\mathcal{L(w_t,m_t,x_t)}=V(w_t,m_t,x_t)-\lambda w_{t+1}$$

Comment: I think you have the right object in mind, but the Lagrangian for this problem will be a whole lot more complex than that. I don't mean to shirk it, but it would be quite a bit of work even to write it down correctly. (You will have one lambda for each constraint, and some of these will be functions of the time t+1 information set, for example.) But basically, it is the function from which all the first-order conditions are derived. I expect that the first-order conditions are the focus of the analysis. Actually "solving" the Bellman equation is probably not part of it.

Comment: I understand your way of thinking but it makes me a little scared...about how to solve the Bellman equation :). Anyway, I will try to give it a shot one of these days...I hope...

Comment: Don't be scared. The approach that noob2 probably had in mind has been described in this wonderful book here https://oxford.universitypressscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780195101928.001.0001/acprof-9780195101928 a comparison of the Bellman approach and how to solve the same problem using a Lagrange function can be found in the first two chapters.